# Determine closest hex values for foreground colours provided by tput

Tags: bash

Is there a way to determine the closest hex values for foreground colours provided by `tput` ?

Comment: Hex is a base-16 numbering system. Do you mean 24-bit RGB? Or HLS? Or another encoding of colour?

Comment: In the format `ff0000`

Comment: RGB or HSL (sorry, not HLS) or some other encoding?

Comment: The hex, example `#ff0000`.

Comment: I wonder whether it is best to use `\e` or `\033`.

Comment: See the `tohex` function in accepted answer to the duplicate Q&A. Also check the answer by ThomasDickey there (he's the maintainer of xterm and ncurses (where your tput likely comes from))